# make hubconnection.start() only once in the whole app

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr

I am using the singalR package in order to use websocket in my application. During the writing of my program, I was advised to use `await hubconnection.start` only once and throughout the whole application. Is it possible? I thought that I could run this task somehow in the background and not make every websocket request start every time I want to use some kind of request. Is this possible or is this the wrong idea?

now I an trying to split up the whole thing and found out that in initState we can create method which will be start first before all others code in app, so I decided to split it up like that(in educational purpose I declaired connection setting globally in my file)

```
final httpConnectionOptions = HttpConnectionOptions(
    accessTokenFactory: () => SharedPreferenceService().loginWithToken(),
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets);
final hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(
      'http://secureLink/mysocket',
      options: httpConnectionOptions,
    )
    .build();
```

this is my class:

```
class TestClass extends StatefulWidget {
  bool? gpsenabled;
  TestClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestClass> createState() => _TestClassState();
}

class _TestClassState extends State<TestClass> {
  void checkGPS() async {
    if (hubConnection.state == HubConnectionState.Connected) {
      await hubConnection.invoke('GPSEnable').then((value) {
        setState(() {
          widget.gpsenabled = value as bool;
        });
        print(widget.gpsenabled);
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
        checkGPS();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      hubConnection.start();
      print('connection first');
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
```

Comment: if it doesnt depend on context, you can put it above runApp